# Composing functions of functions in Mathematica

Tags: functional-programming, wolfram-mathematica, currying

I would like define an operator in which the input and output are each functions.  For example, say I have

```
op1[f_,x_,y_,z_]:= f[y,x,z]
op2[f_,x_,y_,z_]:=f[x,z,y]
```

I would like to compose `op1` and `op2` to obtain the operator which sends f(x,y,z) to f(z,x,y), for example.  However, expressions such as `op1[op2[f,x,y,z],x,y,z]` are not properly interpreted by Mathematica.

At the moment the only fix is

```
g[x_,y_,z_]:=op2[f,x,y,z];
result[x_,y_,z_]:=op1[g,x,y,z]
```

1. Vague question: how do I make this less clumsy?
2. Less vague: Is there the notion partial evaluation in Mathematica, so that something like A[f,-,-,-] is properly interpreted as a function of 3 variables?

Answer (score 2):

First, the way you write op1 and op2, they do not operate on f, and do not create a function, just an expression with that function. That's ok but it explains why you do not obtain what you want.

As a middle ground you can do this:

```
 In[1]:= myop1[f_][x_, y_, z_] := f[y, x, z];

 In[2]:= myop2[f_][x_, y_, z_] := f[x, z, y];

 In[3]:= myop2[myop1[g]][a, b, c]

 Out[3]= g[c, a, b]
```

This is quite close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `Composition` for that: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html

```
Composition[op1,op2][x,y,z]
```

In general refer to http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FunctionalProgramming.html for functional programming related features.